# How to Install grub bootloader for Ubuntu 16.04 into a USB drive (Sandisk cruzer blade)?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, bootloader, usb-installation

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 (32 bit) into my USB drive. But in last section of installation i got an error that is cannot install bootloader to my USB device. I don’t know why it is so. But Ubuntu is successfully installed and I can only boot into it thorough my computer. And can’t boot Ubuntu in my usb in any other PC. I need to install a bootloader to my USB so that I can even boot into my Ubuntu in any other PC. 
Please help me.

Comment: When doing a Full install to USB I use "Something else" when partitioning. Confirm that the USB drive is selected in the bootloader drop down and not a partition, ie sdx not sdxn.

Comment: I used sdb to install bootloader

Comment: Once had this problem, UUID in /etc/fstab was wrong, not same as actual boot partition.

Comment: Try `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` X being the disk (sda, b or c etc) not partition. What does it say.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this. During installation I have made another partition of fat32 type and I had successfully installed grub bootloader in my device.